# Cannot access certain environment variables set in ssh_config

Tags: ssh, batch, environment-variables

I've put together a `batch` script that provisions a development server:

```
@echo off

set mode=development
set ssh_port=22
set secure_ssh_port=4096

if "%mode%" == "development" (
    
    @REM Spin up a new vagrant box
    vagrant destroy -f && vagrant up

    @REM Copy scripts to server
    scp -P %ssh_port% -F ssh_config -r scripts/* dev:/tmp

    @REM Enable SSH variables
    ssh -p %ssh_port% -F ssh_config dev "sudo bash /tmp/_enable-ssh-vars.sh"

    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /f %%i in ('dir /b "scripts\*.sh"') do (
       set x=%%i
       if not "!x:~0,1!" == "_" (
          ssh -p %ssh_port% -F ssh_config dev "sudo bash /tmp/!x!"
          set /p _ignore=Press any key to continue ...
       )
    )
    endlocal
    
    @REM Activate the firewall
    ssh -p %ssh_port% -F ssh_config dev "sudo awall activate --force"
    
    @REM Cleanup
    ssh -p %secure_ssh_port% -F ssh_config dev "sudo rm -rf /tmp/*.sh && sudo cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history && exit"
) else (
   echo "Not implemented"
)
```

My problem is after I run the script to enable variables to be passed over SSH I can not access one of the variables and get the error: `/tmp/1-mkuser.sh: line 20: LC_SSH_PUB_KEY: unbound variable`

Here is the contents of `1-mkuser.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Script to setup new user and add key to authorized keys

set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -o nounset
# set -o xtrace

# Create unprivilaged user ####################################################

adduser --disabled-password "${LC_UNPRIV_USER}"

# Add public key to authorized keys ###########################################
key_path="/home/${LC_UNPRIV_USER}/.ssh"

mkdir -p "${key_path}"
echo "${LC_SSH_PUB_KEY}" > "${key_path}/authorized_keys"
chmod 700 "${key_path}"
chmod 600 "${key_path}/authorized_keys"
```

I get no error about `LC_UNPRIV_USER`, so I assume it's just the `LC_SSH_PUB_KEY` variable causing the problem?

If I login to the box and check if `LC_SSH_PUB_KEY` is set, it is (tested with, and without, sudo). I login using:

```
ssh -p 22 -F ssh_config dev
```

And checking for `LC_SSH_PUB_KEY` returns ...

```
alpine313:~$ sudo echo ${LC_SSH_PUB_KEY}
ssh-rsa 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
```

**Note:** This is a dummy key used for demonstration purposes.

Here is my `ssh_config` on client side:

```
Host dev
    HostName dev.local
    User vagrant
    IdentityFile .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
    SetEnv LC_MODE=development LC_DOMAIN=dev.local LC_IFACE=eth1 LC_SSH_PORT=4096 LC_UNPRIV_USER=deploy LC_SSH_PUB_KEY="ssh-rsa AAAAB3..."

Host prod-root
    HostName production-machine.com
    User root
    IdentityFile keys/toor

Host prod
    HostName production-machine.com
    User deploy
    IdentityFile keys/deploy

Host *
    Port 4096
    Compression yes
    LogLevel INFO
```

And here is the contents of `_enable-ssh-vars.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -o nounset
# set -o xtrace

echo "AcceptEnv LC_*" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
rc-service sshd restart
```

Any ideas what is going wrong?

**Edit** In this instance it's safe to append to `sshd_config`. I have a script that copies a custom hardened version of `sshd_config` in the provision loop. I call the script to allow the `LC_*` variables first so that I have the variables available for the provision scripts.

Here is the origional `sshd_config` after appending `AcceptEnv...`:

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
#UsePAM no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
# Feel free to re-enable these if your use case requires them.
GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding no
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitRootLogin yes

UseDNS no

AllowTcpForwarding yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
```

Comment: "echo "AcceptEnv LC_*" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config" depending on what's in your sshd_config, it's possible that line doesn't apply to all connections. Rather than just appending to the file, you should edit the file make sure the line is in the correct place.

Comment: Updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's better to store the environment variables in the host's environment and use `SendEnv LC_*` to pass those over SSH.

The actual issue here though is the length of the `LC_SSH_PUB_KEY` variable was too long. I'm not sure what the `SetEnv` or `SendEnv` variable limit is.

It's also easier to `scp` the public key, and move it as opposed to storing the public key contents in a variable.